# What's the differences between return undefined & return Promise.resolve() in async function?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

Hi guys~ I found an interesting thing with the return value of async function.

There are two codes:

```
async function test () {
  return Promise.resolve(undefined)
}

async function test () {
  return undefined
}
```

So what's differences between them?

If you say, 'They are the same thing' just like I did, then I'm confused with this code:

```
async function async1() {
  console.log("async1 start");
  await async2();
  console.log("async1 end");
}
async function async2() {
  console.log('async2 start');
   // return Promise.resolve();
}
async1();
new Promise(function (resolve) {
  console.log("Promise 1 start");
  resolve();
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 1");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 2");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 3");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 4");
});
```

In Chrome 73 you will get:

```
async1 start
async2 start
Promise 1 start
async1 end
Then 1
Then 2
Then 3
Then 4
```

Now if we `return Promise.resolve()` in the async2 function:

```
async function async1() {
  console.log("async1 start");
  await async2();
  console.log("async1 end");
}
async function async2() {
  console.log('async2 start');
  return Promise.resolve();
}
async1();
new Promise(function (resolve) {
  console.log("Promise 1 start");
  resolve();
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 1");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 2");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 3");
}).then(function () {
  console.log("Then 4");
});
```

In Chrome 73 you will get:

```
async1 start
async2 start
Promise 1 start
Then 1
Then 2
async1 end
Then 3
Then 4
```

amazing? Notice that, the `async1 end` is different with the first situation just because we `return Promise.resolve()` in async2 function.

By the way, the Code in Chrome 70 is different with Chrome 73.

The first in Chrome 70 you will get

```
async1 start
async2 start
Promise 1 start
Then 1
Then 2
async1 end
Then 3
Then 4
```

And the second in Chrome 70 you will get

```
async1 start
async2 start
Promise 1 start
Then 1
Then 2
Then 3
async1 end
Then 4
```

The difference between Chrome 70 & 73 may be the reason in this blog:
https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async

So the Chrome 73 seems be the right behavior in the future. But I'm still confused, what's the differences between return undefined & return Promise.resolve() in async function?

Comment: If you want to have even _more_ fun, remove `async` from the `async2()` call in the `async1()` function that _does not return a promise_ (your first example).

Comment: Unless I’m missing something, isn’t this just due to the nature if it being asynchronous?

Comment: _"So what's differences between them?"_  [explicit promise creation anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/283366). TL;DR - `return ...` resolves the async function return value (a promise). `return Promise.resolve(...)` does the same only it resolves with another promise that itself resolves immediately

Comment: @Phil If so, `return Promise.resolve()` will be more faster than `return undefined`.While the result is the opposite

Answer (score 0):

They both do return exactly the same thing, just at different times of the event loop.

Referencing the spec: (**Run the code snippet to see the spec section.**)

As you can see, in step 3.d.1 the Promise is resolved immediately (as step 3.b. says *Assert: If we return here*. (As your first example does)

On the other hand, when a Promise is returned the sequence continues on until after Step 7 runs the `AsyncFunctionAwait` (25.5.5.3) and finally in step 8 is returned. (as your second example does)

Here is the reference from the spec:
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start.

```html
<emu-clause id="sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-start" aoid="AsyncFunctionStart">
  <h1><span class="secnum">25.5.5.2</span>AsyncFunctionStart ( <var>promiseCapability</var>, <var>asyncFunctionBody</var> )</h1>
  <emu-alg>
    <ol>
      <li>Let <var>runningContext</var> be the
        <emu-xref href="#running-execution-context" id="_ref_6309"><a href="#running-execution-context">running execution context</a></emu-xref>.</li>
      <li>Let <var>asyncContext</var> be a copy of <var>runningContext</var>.</li>
      <li>Set the code evaluation state of <var>asyncContext</var> such that when evaluation is resumed for that
        <emu-xref href="#sec-execution-contexts" id="_ref_6310"><a href="#sec-execution-contexts">execution context</a></emu-xref> the following steps will be performed:
        <ol type="a">
          <li>Let <var>result</var> be the result of evaluating <var>asyncFunctionBody</var>.</li>
          <li>Assert: If we return here, the async function either threw an exception or performed an implicit or explicit return; all awaiting is done.</li>
          <li>Remove <var>asyncContext</var> from the
            <emu-xref href="#execution-context-stack" id="_ref_6311"><a href="#execution-context-stack">execution context stack</a></emu-xref> and restore the
            <emu-xref href="#sec-execution-contexts" id="_ref_6312"><a href="#sec-execution-contexts">execution context</a></emu-xref> that is at the top of the
            <emu-xref href="#execution-context-stack" id="_ref_6313"><a href="#execution-context-stack">execution context stack</a></emu-xref> as the
            <emu-xref href="#running-execution-context" id="_ref_6314"><a href="#running-execution-context">running execution context</a></emu-xref>.</li>
          <li>If <var>result</var>.[[Type]] is
            <emu-const>normal</emu-const>, then
            <ol>
              <li>Perform !&nbsp;
                <emu-xref aoid="Call" id="_ref_6315"><a href="#sec-call">Call</a></emu-xref>(<var>promiseCapability</var>.[[Resolve]],
                <emu-val>undefined</emu-val>, «
                <emu-val>undefined</emu-val>»).</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Else if <var>result</var>.[[Type]] is
            <emu-const>return</emu-const>, then
            <ol>
              <li>Perform !&nbsp;
                <emu-xref aoid="Call" id="_ref_6316"><a href="#sec-call">Call</a></emu-xref>(<var>promiseCapability</var>.[[Resolve]],
                <emu-val>undefined</emu-val>, «<var>result</var>.[[Value]]»).</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Else,
            <ol>
              <li>Assert: <var>result</var>.[[Type]] is
                <emu-const>throw</emu-const>.</li>
              <li>Perform !&nbsp;
                <emu-xref aoid="Call" id="_ref_6317"><a href="#sec-call">Call</a></emu-xref>(<var>promiseCapability</var>.[[Reject]],
                <emu-val>undefined</emu-val>, «<var>result</var>.[[Value]]»).</li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>Return.</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Push <var>asyncContext</var> onto the
        <emu-xref href="#execution-context-stack" id="_ref_6318"><a href="#execution-context-stack">execution context stack</a></emu-xref>; <var>asyncContext</var> is now the
        <emu-xref href="#running-execution-context" id="_ref_6319"><a href="#running-execution-context">running execution context</a></emu-xref>.</li>
      <li>Resume the suspended evaluation of <var>asyncContext</var>. Let <var>result</var> be the value returned by the resumed computation.</li>
      <li>Assert: When we return here, <var>asyncContext</var> has already been removed from the
        <emu-xref href="#execution-context-stack" id="_ref_6320"><a href="#execution-context-stack">execution context stack</a></emu-xref> and <var>runningContext</var> is the currently
        <emu-xref href="#running-execution-context" id="_ref_6321"><a href="#running-execution-context">running execution context</a></emu-xref>.</li>
      <li>Assert: <var>result</var> is a normal completion with a value of
        <emu-val>undefined</emu-val>. The possible sources of completion values are
        <emu-xref aoid="AsyncFunctionAwait" id="_ref_6322"><a href="#sec-async-functions-abstract-operations-async-function-await">AsyncFunctionAwait</a></emu-xref> or, if the async function doesn't await anything, the step 3.g above.</li>
      <li>Return.
      </li>
    </ol>
  </emu-alg>
</emu-clause>
```

Comment: But why is it slower in timing than 2 instead of 1 microtask?

Comment: The extra internal processing (internal function calls, creation of internal objects, etc.) delay the second example's Promise microtask from getting onto the queue sooner - hence it completes later.

Comment: I can understand why it is slow, but it is slower with two microtasks, that's why I don't understand. 
I think it should only be slower than one microtask?